# Proving that union of two equivalence relations may not be equivalence but intersection is always

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

How do we show that if $R$ and $S$ are two equivalence relations, then $R\cup S$ may/may not be a equivalence relation but $R\cap S$ is always a equivalence relation rigorously.

> i can show it by example as take $A$ set to be $\{1,2,3\}$, then $R=\{ (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,1)\}$ and $S = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,3),(3,1)\}$ are both equivalence but $R\cup S$ is not since it needs to have $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$ in it too but intersection contains the identity one which is equivalence relation.

Comment: You can show it satisfies the definition of equivalent relation from the assumption.

Comment: Thanks understood @aerile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *counterexample* is sufficient to show that such a union is *not always* an equivalence relation.  So you have done that.

However, a single *example* is **insufficient** to show that such intersections will *always* be an equivalence relation.  Rather, you need to prove that there can be *no counterexamples*.

You may do this by proving that $R\cap S$ will be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, whenever both $R$ and $S$ are.  To begin, here's a proof for the inheritance of reflexivity.

> For any $\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle} x\in A$, it is that $\<x,x\>\in R$ and $\<x,x\>\in S$, because $R$ and $S$ are reflexive, and therefore $\<x,x\>\in R\cap S$ (by definition of 'intersection'), meaning the intersection is reflexive too.

Answer (score 1):

Rigorous proof

Is $R\cup S$ and/or $R\cap S$ reflexive?

If $a\in A$ then $(a,a)\in R$ and $(a,a) \in S$ because both are equiv.  So $(a,a) \in R\cup S$ and $(a,a)\in R\cap S$.  So both are reflexive.

Is $R\cup S$ and/or $R\cap S$ symmetric?

Suppose $(a,b) \in R\cup S$.  Then either $(a,b) \in R$ or $(a,b) \in S$ (or both).  If the first case then $(b,a)\in R$ as $R$ is reflexive. And in the second case $(b,a) \in S$ as $S$ is reflexive.  So either $(b,a) \in R$ or $(b,a) \in S$.  So $(b,a) \in R\cup S$ and $R\cup S$ is symmetric.

If $(a,b) \in R\cap S$ then $(a,b) \in R$ and $(a,b) \in S$.  As both are equivalent rel, we must have $(b,a) \in R$ and we must have $(b,a) \in S$ so $(b,a) \in R \cap S$.  So $R\cap S$ is symmetric.

It's transitive where things get interesting.  Do you have an intuition that if $(a,b),(b,c)$ are both in $R\cap S$ then $(a,c) \in R\cap S$?  But do you have intuition why that will go pear shape if $(a,b),(b,c)\in R\cup S$ that $(a,c)$ need not be?  (Hint: what if $(a,b)\in R$ but not $S$ and $(b,c)\in S$ but not $R$?)